# no matching function for call to Persistent<Function>::New(Isolate*&,Local<Function>&)

Tags: c++, node.js

I met this error when writting a nodejs c/c++ addon, it occurred when I try store a async callback in Persistent.

But I found the declaration in v8.h: V8_INLINE  Persistent (Isolate *isolate, Local< S > that). Seems nothing is wrong with the call.

Attach my code. Thank you in advance! It confused me days.

```
struct reqData
{
    int result;
    int a;
    int b;
    char name[128];
    Persistent<Function> callback;
}; 

static Handle<Value> test(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
    Isolate *isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    if ( args.Length() < 3 || !args[0]->IsNumber() || !args[1]->IsNumber() )
    {
        return (*isolate).ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Bad argument")));
    }

    ssize_t int1 ( args[0]->Int32Value() );
    ssize_t int2 ( args[1]->Int32Value() );
    char nameBuffer[128] = {0};
    args[2]->ToString()->WriteOneByte(nameBuffer);

    if ( args[3]->IsFunction() )
    {
        Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[3]);

        reqData* request = new reqData;
        request->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(isolate,callback);



        request->a = int1;
        request->b = int2;
        strcpy(request->name, nameBuffer);

        uv_work_t* req = new uv_work_t();
        req->data = request;

        uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), req, workerFunc, afterWorkFunc);
    }
    else
    {
        return (*isolate).ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Callback missing")));
    }

    return Undefined(isolate);
}

extern "C"
{
    // equal to js
    //
    // exports.test = function Test(){};
    //
    static void init(Local<Object> exports)
    {
        //target->Set(String::NewSymbol("asyncAddon"), FunctionTemplate::New(test)->GetFunction());
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "asyncAddon", test);
    }
}

NODE_MODULE(asyncAddon, init)
```

Comment: What version of node are you building against?

Comment: @mscdex Node.js v6.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is that you don't do `Persistent<..>::New()`, you just `.Reset()` with the value you want to store in the `Persistent`. For example:

```cpp
request->callback.Reset(isolate, callback);
```

Other things to note:

- You don't need a `HandleScope` in `test()` because the function is already being called directly from JavaScript, so there is already an active scope. You only need a `HandleScope` when you're using the V8 API on the main thread, having come from the libuv thread pool or some other place that is not directly from JS land.
- You should really consider using [`nan`](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/). It helps smooth over differences across V8 versions and allows you to not have to worry about details like isolates and other things.
- If you're not already familiar with them, there are V8 API docs online [here](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/).

Comment: This really helps, especially the notes! Thanks you!